# Does the XA specification ensure that any transaction arrive at the resources in the same order?

Tags: distributed-transactions, distributed-caching

Within an application I am trying to build a cache for a connected RBMS.

- Mutations to the cache and the database need to be done in transactions.
- For matters of this question, cache and database form a distribtuted transactional system, where each of the two resources has its own specific implementation for the ACID guarantee.
- For simplicity of the question lets pretend any transaction is executed in the SERIALIZABLE isolation level.

**Which kind of serialization assurance does the XA protocol provide?**

To point out what this question is targeting, please allow me to clarify a few things first:

I understood 2PC is not about implementing ACID with repsect to the individual object mutations, which is the resources job.
I understood 2PC is (trying to) aim for atomic execution of the transaction, that is in a all-or-nothing manner. The XA and JSR-907 JTA specification indicate that a resource manager interface may be used from multiple threads and go to show that such can imply any work between the start() and end() methods be executed in parallel to the commit processing methods. But there's nothing detailed with respect to how commits are processed, and whether 2PC commit processing is necessariliy happen sequentially!

### Arbitration order impacts the state of the data

[Serializable](https://jepsen.io/consistency/models/serializable) is a consistency model which is imposing a total order on the transaction which is not guaranteed to be consistent with the real time order. This means transactions Tx1 and Tx2 when committed in this order may become effecive on the system in order Tx2 Tx1. The order in which transaction become effective on the system is called by [Viotti and Vukolić](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.00168.pdf) the arbitration order.

However, I percieve the arbitration order is not just the result of the system specific serialization algorithm, but particularly when seen from a client, result of the fact that every operation "takes time": Threads are scheduled arbitrarily, memory access takes time, I/O and Network packages are all subject to non-deterministic effects. The order of actions as seen by one process ist not necessaily the order percieved by another process (see [Aphyr](https://aphyr.com/posts/313-strong-consistency-models) for an in-depth explanation). It's this part of the arbitration order that this question is focussing on.

Serializable therefore only guarantees whichever order happend to get established, such order is not introducing a state of the data that was "illegal" as seen by it's transaction. However, the total order has an impact on the absolute state of the data: Suppose Tx1 writes x1=x+x and Tx2 writes x2=x*x. Those are not kommutative.

### Reformulated question

**Does the XA protocol provide any guarantee beyond transaction atomicity?

Do transaction manager with the help of the 2PC ensure linearization of transaction commit initiation such that any transaction-prepare/commit/rollback arrive at the resource in the same order  (and meet [sequential consistency](https://jepsen.io/consistency/models/sequential) on the transaction-item level)?**

As an example:
Assume we have `XA resources C(ache) and D(atabase)`. The Cache resource contained objects which need to remain consistent with the Database. For simplicity we say C and D both contain object x. Assume we have transactions Tx1 and Tx2. `Tx1 writes x1 and Tx2 writes x2`. Tx1 and Tx2 commit to the TransactionManager "in close succession".

Will the XA protocol, or contemporary TMs in general, permit the following *commit initiation sequences* to happen?

```
C: Tx1, Tx2
D: Tx2, Tx1
```

While all four transaction-parts are executed by the resources locally in SERIALIZABLE isolation still, the outcome is violating our data consistency!

```
C:x2, formally: x1<<x2
D:x1, formally: x2<<x1
```

If transaction managers performed transaction commit processing stricly sequentially, the example above was prevented (However, such did of course not preclude above outcome due to differences in the resource specific/internal arbitration order).

[Distributed serialization annomalies](http://rhaas.blogspot.com/2010/07/distributed-serialization-anomalies.html) appear to be a less accessible studied subject. While [Some authors](https://sites.google.com/site/yoavraz2/home/theory-of-commitment-ordering) focus on effects of different arbitration orders produced by different kinds or serialization mechanisms, [others](http://dbmsmusings.blogspot.com/2019/06/correctness-anomalies-under.html) focus on the "time of arrival" aspect (which this question does). Even if there might be no full soution available (with respect to the CAP theroem), i question if the XA protocol is accounting for at least a part of the problem.